# Time machine can't find backup on Synology through Finder, but present when viewed through Synology disk station

Tags: finder, time-machine, nas, macos

I'm having a strange issue with Time Machine which is stored on a Synology ds215j. If I go to finder, I can navigate to the shared directory and see my girlfriend's time machine .sparsebundle file - but mine is no longer there. In its place is a package titled "AD4GNS~X". Clicking it opens a terminal window to its location. I can't view the package contents. I'm suspecting this is my backup rendered in some strange format I can't access.

However, when going into my Synology disk station via the web app, it correctly shows my .sparsebundle. I don't know why Finder is displaying something differently than the Synology disk station.

I'm running Mac OS Sierra build 16A320. Perhaps it's a permissions issue but I'm scratching my head as to why this is happening all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to connect using afp://[your synology IP] then select the share point manually, and likewise in the Time Machine preferences pane. This seems to be a known issue with macOS Sierra.